# ListView drawsubitem - column is not selected

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Why the 4`th column is not selected? I use listView3_DrawSubItem and e.DrawDefault = true; for that column and now is not selectable.

[image: Selection]

Edit:
The listView1_DrawSubItem code:

```
        // Only interested in 2nd column.
        if (e.Header != this.action)
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
            return;
        }
        drawItem(e);
```

And the drawitem code:

```
        string drawString = e.SubItem.Text;
        float size = 8.25F;

        e.DrawBackground();

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(DesktopCleaner.Properties.Resources.folder_icon_512x512);

        if (drawString == "Leave on Desktop")
        {
            image = new Bitmap(DesktopCleaner.Properties.Resources.desk);

        }
        else if (drawString == "Recycle")
        {
            image = new Bitmap(DesktopCleaner.Properties.Resources.recyclebin_preview_1);

        }
        else if (drawString == "Delete")
        {
            image = new Bitmap(DesktopCleaner.Properties.Resources.free_vector_delete_icon_101805_Delete_icon);

        }

        var imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y, image.Width - 2, image.Height - 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, imageRect);

        System.Drawing.Font drawFont = new System.Drawing.Font(listView1.Font.FontFamily, size, FontStyle.Bold);
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush drawBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

        System.Drawing.StringFormat drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat();
        var strrect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 18, e.Bounds.Y + 3, 150, e.Bounds.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, strrect, drawFormat);
```

Comment: It probably is selected but it doesn't show. How do you draw the selection? Where do the icons come from when you have `e.DrawDefault = true`? Can you show us the `DrawSubItem` code?

Comment: I just updated the question.

Comment: You are ignoring e.ItemState.  Don't.

Comment: Don`t understand. Where and for what should I use e.ItemState?

Comment: As I see, if I select all items, or a part and right click, select something from contextmenu it will affect only focused row. How I make for all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are responsible for drawing the selection.

So even if you use the nice methods:

```
e.DrawBackground();
e.DrawText();
```

no selection is being drawn.

So you need to use `FillRectangle` and `DrawString` with the appropriate `Colors`, maybe like this:

```
 bool selected = e.Item.Selected;
 using ( SolidBrush backBrush = new SolidBrush( 
         selected? SystemColors.MenuHighlight :SystemColors.Window ) )
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, e.Bounds);
 using (SolidBrush textBrush = new SolidBrush(
         selected ? Color.White : Color.Black        ))
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, yourFont, textBrush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
```

The code is simplified; you'll use your coodinates to make room for the icons etc..